# How does "review" work?

Tags: support

I'm new to SE sites, and today I noticed a "review" link on the top menu/banner for RPG.SE (but not on other SE sites).

I looked into the about and faq pages for both the main site and the meta site; but couldn't find more detail than the brief paragraph on the first item in the list.

The *way* it works is pretty self-explanatory, but I'm wondering if there's something written somewhere as to the *intended* mechanic for reviews.

For starters:
Is this written down somewhere? (and I just missed it)
Or, for example, at what point did I earn this privilege?

What is expected from a review?
I remember the comments on my first answers (no chatty stuff) and I recognize some do-s and don't-s from the faq and from reading other posts (relevant questions, ask a real question, etc.)

Is that all there is to reviewing?

For the record, I can only review new posts and late answers so far.

Comment: I'll try to work up a proper answer to your questions later, but for right now read [How does the /review page work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74238/how-does-the-review-page-work) and [What is the newly added Review section?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88968/what-is-the-newly-added-review-section) on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: That's the gist of it.  There are no hard and fast rules like "You must do X when reviewing."  The idea is to get eyes on posts that may need attention.  Just do what you'd do when you see any other post.

Comment: Over at TeX.SX we have a list of [building blocks to help reviewers out](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks); Perhaps we could do the same here?

Comment: I created a community wiki answer with your contributions.

Comment: @Canageek Do it! Standardising some of our commenting would be useful, I think. Everything SE is CC-licensed, so starting with a copy-paste of that meta post should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The review page is just a community tool to automatically identify posts which are likely to need some reviewing.

Note that when you reach 200 rep, the review menu [appears in the top menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84693/eeeek-i-sense-an-eeeek-question-about-missing-a-unanswered-tab/88954#88954) and will be replaced with a "tools" menu when you reach 10k.

From @C. Ross:

> There are no hard and fast rules like "You must do X when reviewing." The idea is to get eyes on posts that may need attention. Just do what you'd do when you see any other post.

You might also want to check the [FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) and the following posts from other SE sites:

- [How does the /review page work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74238/how-does-the-review-page-work)
- [What is the newly added Review section?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88968/what-is-the-newly-added-review-section)
- [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) (common replies for TeX.SX)
- [Please make /review route available as a link somewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75572/please-make-review-route-available-as-a-link-somewhere)